# What will happen if I choose a higher value capacitor for ESD protection than the recommended value?

Tags: capacitor, protection, esd

I want to protect my circuit from ESD, for which I have chosen a  capacitor as ESD protection due to size and cost.

I have chosen a KEMET 1000 pF 16V with 25 kV breakdown voltage  capacitor value according to my requirements.

What if I go with 0.1 uF capacitor which higher than my calculated value of 1000 pF? Will it affect my circuit performance?

Update:

Here's the schematic:

[image]

As shown above, the input pin (connected to the PCB connectors) is pulled up with 5k resistor and below that the ESD capacitor is placed to protect it from ESD.

What if I go with a higher value, say 0.1uf? How will it affect my circuit and its response against ESD?

Here is the calculation that I am referring to:

[image]

- Co=150pF (capacitor inside the ESD gun)
- Cx= 1000pF
- Vo=15kV

If I substitute the values in this formula, I get Vx as =
Vx = 5kv

[Reference for calculation.](https://product.tdk.com/en/contact/faq/capacitors-0097.html)

I also referred to (this question.]([How to choose capacitor voltage rating for ESD protection?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/597679/how-to-choose-capacitor-voltage-rating-for-esd-protection))

We are going with 16kV breakdown voltage because for air discharge the ESD peak goes up to 15kV. Considering all factors we finalized the ESD value 1000pF 16kV

Comment: The increased capacitor doesn't know or care about your signal or ESD. It just absorbs energy from everything and slows everything down, both ESD and regular signals.

Comment: If they are on power lines, the increased capacitance will also affect your inrush current.  That being a significant issue or not will depend on your specific circuit.

Comment: We need a schematic of your protection circuit.

Comment: A capacitor with 25kV breakdown voltage will be relatively large, such as [these](https://www.vishay.com/docs/22139/fpzpez.pdf) 140mm diameter disk capacitors.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Model your circuit in a simulator, add the capacitor and check if it affects performance or functionality.

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: What does your calculation say about the new value? What does that suggest about the required ratings of R21 and R36? What other effects might the capacitor have: signal bandwidth for example?