# How can I utilize PSpice for ESD simulation?

Tags: simulation, esd, pspice

Issue: I do not know how to build a ESD simulation model in PSpice Orcad capture.

Question: What is wrong with the simulation circuit? The simulation result seems like the ESD is not discharging properly. Why I cannot see the same response as the simulation result in the reference?

- For the second simulation result, I set to close the switch at 5 μs. How come the voltage at C2 behaves as if it is connected to 25 kV before the first 5 μs?

Simulation conditions:

- Conform ISO 10605 (voltage range -25 kV to +25 kV, discharge capacitor: 330 pF, discharge resistor: 2000 Ohm)
- Simulation time: 20 μs
- Switch opens at 0.1 μs
- Switch closes at 5 μs

*ESD circuit with open switch at T:*
[image: ESD circuit with Open switch at T]

*Simulation result 1:*
[image: Simulation result 1]

*ESD circuit with close switch at T:*
[image: ESD circuit with Close switch at T]

*Simulation result 2:*
[image: Simulation result 2]

Reference:
[How to choose capacitor voltage rating for ESD protection?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/597679/how-to-choose-capacitor-voltage-rating-for-esd-protection)

Could anyone give a guidance or feedback?

Comment: Surely you need switch normally open, and *closes* at t > 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Switch opens at 0.1 uS*

Prior to the switch opening, all the capacitors in your circuit will be fully charged to 25 kV. This is an inevitability of your circuit and, your graph indicates that. After the switch opens, the state of charge of all the capacitors will be exactly the same. This is also as shown in the graph.

> *Could anyone give a guidance or feedback?*

If you are simulating an ESD gun then you should charge C1 (330 pF) with the switch open then, close the switch but, you should also disengage V1 at that very moment to prevent V1 from having any effect. Some point later you should open the switch labelled U1 and restart the process as desired.